# CSS-Transition on a div with centered text (vertical/horizontal)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

I am struggeling to achieve an acceptable transition on a div element which contains text that is centered, both vertically and horizontally.

The span element with the text moves with the transition to the top and creates this ugly fade-out effect. I've stumbled across [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078768/how-do-i-stop-my-text-from-moving-when-css-transition-occurs) but unfortunately it didn't help that much to work with an absolute position on a span wrapper element.

[image]
[image]

### HTML

```html
<!-- Success -->
<div class="panel panel-default action-message-div message-panel-success" ng-hide="lobby.actionMessage.isError === null || lobby.actionMessage.isError === true">
  <span class="action-message-span">{{lobby.actionMessage.data}}</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
.action-message-div {
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}


.action-message-span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}

.message-panel-success {
  border: 2px solid #008000;
  background-color: #90EE90;
}

.message-panel-success.ng-hide-add, .message-panel-success.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: all ease-out 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 1s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out 1s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out 1s;
  -ms-transition: all ease-out 1s;
}

.message-panel-success.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

### Solution

The `line-height: 0;` in `message-panel-success.ng-hide` was screwing up my css - of course you can't change that from 75px to 0.

Comment: Can you JSfiddle this? Would be easier to play with.

Comment: I've found the typo and added it to the initial post.